# Running devices tab opening automatically in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio Flamingo there is a tab called **Running Devices** and it's opening automatically after each **Run Application**, is there a way to disable this automatic opening?

I tried to disable **Enable mirroring of physical Android devices** option but the tab still opened automatically.

[image]

Comment: Could be a bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/278424781

Comment: What an annoying bug!

Comment: it frustates they should have fixed this bug moving ahead..why are they releasing future builds without making previous Versions stable...Absolutely irresponsible...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Based on this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/278424781) on the issue tracker, this is fixed in Android Studio Giraffe. Thanks @dominicoder

[image]

Comment: is there any solution to this issue in android studio Flamingo?

Comment: @AliAsjad yes, Tools > Device mirroring, then unselect the "Enable mirroring of physical Android devices"

Comment: @FabioR your solution does not work. Device mirroring is something else completely. The accepted answer has the important option - Open the Running Devices tool window when launching... your solution is straight up false and irrelevant to the original question.

Comment: On Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 1 this setting does not exist for me on Mac 

Answer (score 4):

It's fixed in Android Studio Giraffe (Stable version is out and now not only in beta builds). Update (if you not done it alredy) then go to settings - tools - Device Mirroring. There Will be the Options which control opening "Running Devices" - you can uncheck all three and this must stop automatic opening.
[screenshot of settings window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqPbW.png)

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings -> Tools -> Emulator and uncheck Launch in a tool window like so:

[image]

Comment: it's not about the emulator. it's about the device mirroring

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround make it Window and it won't popup
[image: screenshot]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34577810)

Comment: @SwetaJain My stackoverflow reputation do not allow to post images.

Answer (score -2):

Android Studio by default presents you with the last workspace you worked with. This might be an issue related to that. As far as I know, there is no toggle or anything related to disabling or enabling this. So, you might instead try, reinstalling the Android Studio. Also, don't worry about your projects, all data will be stored intact.