# How to disable device mirroring in AS Flamingo

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using AS `Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1`

Device mirroring is a good feature, but most of the time I don't need it to be enabled all the time. Everytime I run an app this running device tab will open. I have disabled this in the settings.

[image]

After unchecking, the side tab will still open and I have to constantly close it each time. Electric eel never had this issue.

Is there somewhere to not open the running devices tab?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76014826